# Properly centering div based on child element

Tags: javascript, css, html, roguelike

*This is a repost from StackExchange's GameDev section, yet, I find that the problem seems more applicable to StackOverflow because it pertains more to CSS, JS, and positioning techniques rather than JavaScript topics (mostly UnityScript and Phaser) discussed on the former.*

I've been making a **roguelike-style game** in HTML5 **without using canvas (only divs)** with **pure JS** (**[fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/GrandonBroseph/t38k1j8w/)**). I've been trying to **enlarge the tile size (font size) while keeping the player centered within the camera.** For some reason, when the tile size isn't equal to the map size, the camera will be slightly off.

**Note that the 3D effect is on purpose; I believe it adds some much needed depth, and just looks super cool. :D**

When `tileScale` (line 4 in the fiddle) is `9` (very undesirable; the dots on the player's y axis should be aligned, not at a slight angle):

[image: The camera is off!]

When `tileScale` is `25` (on point!):

[image: The camera is on point.]

Here's some relevant (trimmed) code:

```
window.onresize = function(){
    game.viewportWidth = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
    game.viewportHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
    game.windowSize = Math.min(game.viewportWidth, game.viewportHeight);
    // Droid Sans Mono has a ratio of 3:4 (width:height), conveniently.
    // This may be problematic. I'm not sure.
    game.tileWidth = game.windowSize*.6 / game.tileScale;
    game.tileHeight = game.windowSize*.8 / game.tileScale;
}

// Update the camera position (needs help?)
this.updateCamera = function(){
    // Get player coordinates (-.5 because we need to get the player tile center)
    // times the tileWidth plus the game window (inner square) size divided by two.
    var left = ((-game.player.x-.5)*game.tileWidth+game.windowSize/2)+"px";
    var top = ((-game.player.y-.5)*game.tileHeight+game.windowSize/2)+"px";
    game.planeContainer.style.left = left;
    game.planeContainer.style.top = top;
}
```

**How can I ensure that the dots in the center of the screen will be always lined up, instead of on a slight angle?** My current evidence suggests that the position of the `game.planeContainer` object isn't being established correctly.

I know this is a super-tough problem, so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

*([Another fiddle link, in case you skimmed over the first one. :D](http://jsfiddle.net/GrandonBroseph/t38k1j8w/))*

Answer (score 2):

Remove this line from your css stylings on .inner-text to take out the skew:
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

Comment: This is a bit of an odd hack; that line in `.inner-text` was supposed to center the text within its container div (avoiding weird offsets). This removes the skew, but places the player way off center (decrease `tileScale` for a good look). +1'd for odd insight, yet the root of the problem remains unsolved.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean about placing the player way off center.  The @ still looks centered to me without the translate, even at the lowest tileScales.  What browser/OS are you looking at it in?

Comment: Wait, that's really weird. I tried this a while ago, but the player was way off. [Here's a fiddle of what I'm seeing.](http://jsfiddle.net/GrandonBroseph/t38k1j8w/6/) I'm using Chrome on a Windows 8.1, and if you use _Inspect Element_, _PrtScr_, and an image editor, you can see that the player is slightly off (by 6-25 px or so). Commenting out the `translate` line seems strange to me (as it doesn't completely solve the problem), and I'm still unsure if this has anything to do with CSS.